# Rails ActiveRecord Eager Load takes a long time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using eager loading to join two of my tables

```
Model1.eager_load(:model2)
```

The Model1 table has about 800 rows and has many references to other tables. Whenever that line is called, it takes about 3 minutes to load the view that shows the info.

I then tried making a straight Postgres connection and running the same SQL query that was generated from the eager load and that finished in 50ms.

Why is it taking so much longer in ActiveRecord and is there anyways I can cut down on the time?

In the console, it gets to the following SQL query (this is a simplified version, of course) and it hangs for about 3 minutes before it continues and loads the page.

```
SELECT model1.*, model2.* FROM model1 LEFT OUTER JOIN model2 ON model2
.foreign_key = model1.id
```

Comment: how do you know that the eager_load step is the slow step? can you provide a log trace / more info?

Comment: It gets to the SQL query constructed by the eager_load which I can see in the console, then hangs there for a few minutes before the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that this is not due to eager loading per se, but reflects the overhead of instantiating many model objects. ActiveRecord must initialize objects when retrieving them from a database. You can prove this to yourself by adding a callback to the associated model:

```
after_find :yodel

def yodel
  puts "Yodel-a-e-hoo!"
end
```

This is pretty fast, but it is not instantaneous. When you are getting back many objects, that initialization time will start to affect performance.

The typical solution is to paginate results if possible. Otherwise you may need to re-write the query, using raw SQL if necessary, to be more selective.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried using raw SQL to get the info and that runs very quickly. Is there a conventional way to get the results of a raw SQL query's results into something that is a bit easier to work with?